# Getting values from XML through PHP with muliple namespaces

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to read from an XML file which uses 3 namespaces and struggling to read values from it.

```
<?xml version ="1.0"?> 
<Invoice xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"
xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2"

<cac:PartyName>
<cbc:Name>John Doe</cbc:Name>
</cac:PartyName>
```

My PHP so far after reading several examples, been years since ive written PHP so probably so easy for you guys.

```
<?php

$xml = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('cbc', 
'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2');
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('cac', 
  'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-
 2');

foreach($xml->xpath('//cac:PartyName') as $PartyName)
{
print_r ($PartyName->xpath('//cbc:Name')); 

}

?>
```

I register only two of the namespaces as they are the only ones in use in the XML file. (CBC and CAC). I get results from the entire array from this but i kinda want my output to be just "John Doe".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how much other data you have and where other elements with the same name might be in the document depends on how specific your XPath can be.

```
foreach($xml->xpath('//cac:PartyName') as $PartyName)
{
    echo (string)$PartyName->children('cbc', true)->Name.PHP_EOL;
}
```

The above means that it will be all the data under the `<PartyName>` element and you can then pick out which bits you want.

```
foreach($xml->xpath('//cac:PartyName/cbc:Name') as $PartyName)
{
    echo (string)$PartyName.PHP_EOL;
}
```

This limits it to just pick out the Name elements directly under the PartyName elements, in case the Name elements might exist elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the text content of a `SimpleXMLElement` by just casting it to a string:

```
echo (string) $PartyName->xpath('//cbc:Name')[0];
```

Note the added `[0]` at the end of the line as well - the `xpath` method returns an array of objects, and we just need to refer to the first one.

See https://eval.in/945981